# Cycles Rendering Issue - too dark or too exposed

Tags: cycles-render-engine, settings

I am pretty new to Blender and getting used to the new systems. I have produced a building model in Sketchup and imported it into Blender as a DAE with no issues. I have added a camera move to the model to render out an animation.

The model is overall accurate in size with the longest wall being approx 67m.

The problem i seem to be having is that in the viewport render view it looks as it should, however when i start the actual render it is incredibly dark, despite having a sunlamp in the scene.

I have tried various settings such as light strength etc and nothing brightens it. The exception to this is if i enable the scene world it becomes massively overexposed.

I need this file for a deadline, any help or advise would be appreciated.

Edit: thansk for the feeback thus far. I am unsure why the textures have not pulled through on the link.. In summary see image below to better explain my problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are so many settings we could look at, hard to tell without the file where the problem is...

Comment: Of course, Apologies. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zd50ldqjnn2lmhOMT3o28T2FY75vla9t/view?usp=share_link

Comment: I feel like we are missing a lot here, even with the file. There is no texture (means, the building comes out magenta) and the world is just pitch black.

Comment: Anywho, have a look at CGMatters video on HDRIs, I think this is what you really need for an outdoor shot of a building. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VBkj_I-ONk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first:
Only using a sun lamp to light an outdoor scene is not a good idea, as there are sooo many lightsources outside.
Utilize an HDRI, you can get those on polyhaven.com for example.
Next up: Of yourse your building will look dark when the light has no floor to bounce off of and can illuminate the building further. So, give your building a ground plane to stand on (shift A, plane) and use an HDRI, further fixes can be applied if this should not suffice, but it should give you a foundation to work with.
Note:
An HDRI needs world illumination, so set that back to 1.

Comment: Thank you that's worked and given me a base to tweak from!